# Magento Cloud Autodetect Browser language and redirect

Tags: magento2.4, magento2-cloud

How can I autodetect the user's browser language and redirect to the "right" store view in Magento Commerce Cloud?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reliably use the [HTTP header "Accept-Language"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) then there may be two ways of doing it (rely on the HTTP header availability, so please validate the fallback.)

For example:

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
```

### Using Fastly Custom VCLs

Fastly provides a way of reading this header, process/filter it and apply custom redirect. https://docs.fastly.com/en/guides/accept-language-header-vcl-features

### Using ./magento-vars.php File

PHP provides the ability to parse the HTTP Accept-Language header https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php

- `$locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);`
- `$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);`

You may write your own custom logic on `./magento-vars.php` and do the necessary redirections. .`/magento-vars.php` has the visibility to `$_SERVER`, `$_ENV`, `$_COOKIE` etc.

Multi-store setup and sample snippets can be found on this **DevDocs** link: https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-multi-sites.html#modify-magento-variables

**For an example:**

```
<?PHP


// enable, adjust and copy this code for each store you run
// Store #0, default one

// ./magento-vars.php

function customStoreLogic()
{
    $storeView = false;
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
        return false;
    }

    $locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

    switch ($locale) {
        case "en_US":
            $storeView = 'us_store';
            break;
        default:
            $storeView = 'default';
            break;
    }
    return $storeView;
}

$storeView = customStoreLogic();

if ($storeView) {
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = $storeView;
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = "store";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a multisite setup so my `magento-vars.php` looks a bit different but you gave me the idea of how to :-). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to using javascript for detecting the user language

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
alert(language); //works IE/SAFARI/CHROME/FF
```

If the user language is different from the current store view language, you will redirect to the correct URL using javascript.